# Return Value of load_plugin_textdomain

Tags: plugin-development, translation

Good Day,

I'm trying to translate my plugin but it doesn't seems to work.

I read that I should check the return value of "load_plugin_textdomain" to see if it's false (meaning it doesn't find my translation file), but I cannot find how to find this value.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

*EDIT* As requested here is the lines to load it

```
function ap_action_init() {
    load_plugin_textdomain('my_plugin', false, WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/languages' );
}

// Localization

// Add Actions
add_action('init', 'ap_action_init');
```

Comment: Can you post the code your are using?

Comment: As Requested - The Line has been added

Comment: What if you change `WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/languages'` to `WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my-plugin/languages/'`? Check the path, it seems wrong in your code.

Comment: Yes I just figured out that my path was wrongly written at the same time... 

But can you help me for the next time how to check the return value, that's really my question ;-) Thanks

Comment: You had a problem and you asked about what you thinked was the solution instead of asking about the problem; that is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). [`load_plugin_textdomain()` returns true or false](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain#Return_Values) and you can check the returned value as you usually do with any other PHP function. Where do you exactly have problems with that?

Comment: The question was "I read that I should check the return value of "load_plugin_textdomain" to see if it's false (meaning it doesn't find my translation file), but I cannot find how to find this value." I never asked how to fix my problem... Thanks for helping me with that, but not having too much experience with PHP I needed the information that was given by Frank below. Thanks for your time though. If I just ask how to fix my code I will never learn how to look next time for a return value... And that was the main purpose of my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, checking the value returned by a function is a very basic PHP task I supposed you alreay know. Note that this site is for questions specific to WordPress, general questions about PHP are better asked in StackOverflow where there are PHP expert coders ready to help.

Comment: Try [Debug Translations](https://marketpress.com/product/debug-translations/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
global $langOK;
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_load_textdomain' );
function myplugin_load_textdomain() {
    global $langOK;
    $langOK = load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
}
```

Later you can check the value of `$langOK` ( TRUE = success, FALSE = failure ).

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You could do simply `$langOK = load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );` as `load_plugin_textdomain()` already returns `true` or `false`. I also would return the `true` or `false` in `myplugin_load_textdomain` instead of, or in addition to, using a global variable.

Comment: First part is 100% true. Second - returning value from action callback is pointless as you cannot access it elswhere. You could react to success or failure within the callback by  displaying a message or doing something else.